# How do I access the value of a parameter in the range() function from within a loop?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, parameters, range

I would like to access the `range()` function's parameter values from within a for-loop. I currently have the following working code:

```
import inflect

start = 0
stop = 5
step = 2

o = inflect.engine()

for i in range(start, stop, step):
    print(f"{i} is the {o.number_to_words(o.ordinal((i + step) // step))} "
          f"value when counting from {start} to {stop} by {step}")
```

which produces the following desired output:

```
0 is the first value when counting from 0 to 5 by 2
2 is the second value when counting from 0 to 5 by 2
4 is the third value when counting from 0 to 5 by 2
```

What I would like is a way of generating the same output without first defining `start`, `stop` and `step`. I envision a solution looking something like:

```
import inflect

o = inflect.engine()

for i in range(0, 5, 2):
    start = range.getparameters[0]
    stop = range.getparameters[1]
    step = range.getparameters[2]

    print(f"{i} is the {o.number_to_words(o.ordinal((i + step) // step))} "
          f"value when counting from {start} to {stop} by {step}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields have the same name as the parameters:

```
r = range(1, 10, 2)
print(r.start, r.stop, r.step)
```

Note that this requires assigning the range to a variable before the for loop. Alternatively, you can use an assignment expression if you are using Python 3.8.

Comment: Awesome tidbit about assignment expressions. I'm running 3.7, but it is a compelling reason for me to upgrade.